# AEM New Page vs New Site

Tags: content-management-system, adobe, aem, ecm

If my site structure is like below 
MySite (**SiteName**) 
     --- HomePage (**Page**) 
     --- ProductPage (**Page**)

Under siteadmin console, while creating site **MySite** should I use *"New Page.."*  Or *"New Site.."* ? When to use which option?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**"New site"** option is used  to create a site from an existing **Blueprint**. Blueprint is part of AEM's multisite manager (MSM) functionality. A blueprint is used to create multiple sites with common structure , for example **MySite** in English, French, Spanish and so on.

A Blueprint is created from an existing site. A site is a collection of pages, so you will be using **"New Page"** option for creating the site initially.

So if you don't have **"MySite"** ready as of yet, you'll be using "New page" option. Once "MySite" is ready and you want to create **copies of "MySite"** for different languages and countries to enforce a common structure, you will have to use **"New Site"** option.

You can read more about AEM's MSM capabilities here :

http://dev.day.com/docs/v5_2/html-resources/cq5_guide_power_user/ch13s04.html

http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/administering/multi_site_manager.html

Comment: You can't use the new page option unless it's already inside a site....